# UIButton animation is skipped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I implemented an animation for my buttons to slide into the screen. If the buttons are already inside the screen I want my buttons to first slide outside again and after that to come back.

However the first animation (when buttons are already slided into the screen) is skipped so that the buttons are just jumping instantly outside of the screen
and than slide back.

I want them to slowy slide outside and slowly slide back again.

Its kinda like the `setAnimationDuration` inside the if-clause is ignored:

```
[self.buttonInfoFrame setAlpha:1.0];
[self.buttonSetCourse setAlpha:1.0];
[self.buttonSetCourse setEnabled:YES];

if(![self.selected isEqual: @""])
{
    CGRect frame = self.buttonInfoFrame.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 1050;
    frame.origin.y = 150;

    CGRect frame2 = self.buttonSetCourse.frame;
    frame2.origin.x = 1050;
    frame2.origin.y = 526;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;
    self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

CGRect frame = self.buttonInfoFrame.frame;
frame.origin.x = 757;
frame.origin.y = 150;

CGRect frame2 = self.buttonSetCourse.frame;
frame2.origin.x = 747;
frame2.origin.y = 526;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;
self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: What about selected? A bool, a string, etc?

Comment: slideAnimation is called from 5 different buttons... it is just an identifier which button is pressed... and if no button has bin pressed before the identifier is empty so i dont have to run the first animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your second animation in the completion block of first animation!

**EDIT**

```
   if(![self.selected isEqual: @""])
    {
        CGRect frame = self.buttonInfoFrame.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 1050;
        frame.origin.y = 150;

        CGRect frame2 = self.buttonSetCourse.frame;
        frame2.origin.x = 1050;
        frame2.origin.y = 526;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1,0 delay:0.0 options:option
            animations:^{
                self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;
                self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;
            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                CGRect frame = self.buttonInfoFrame.frame;
                frame.origin.x = 757;
                frame.origin.y = 150;

                CGRect frame2 = self.buttonSetCourse.frame;
                frame2.origin.x = 747;
                frame2.origin.y = 526;

                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:option
                    animations:^{
                        self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;
                        self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
        }];

} else {

    CGRect frame = self.buttonInfoFrame.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 757;
    frame.origin.y = 150;

    CGRect frame2 = self.buttonSetCourse.frame;
    frame2.origin.x = 747;
    frame2.origin.y = 526;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:option
        animations:^{
            self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;
            self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;
        }
        completion:nil];
        }];
}
```

Comment: Two Things: 1. Completion Block of first Animation? 2. The Second Animation is not always the seconds... sometimes its the first and only....

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify the code:

```
[self.buttonInfoFrame setAlpha:1.0];
[self.buttonSetCourse setAlpha:1.0];
[self.buttonSetCourse setEnabled:YES];

CGRect frame = self.buttonInfoFrame.frame;
CGRect frame2 = self.buttonSetCourse.frame;

void (^firstAnimation)() = ^{
   frame.origin.x = 1050;
   frame.origin.y = 150;
   self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;

   frame2.origin.x = 1050;
   frame2.origin.y = 526;
   self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;
};

void (^secondAnimation)() = ^{
   frame.origin.x = 757;
   frame.origin.y = 150;
   self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;

   frame2.origin.x = 747;
   frame2.origin.y = 526;
   self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;
};

void (^onCompletion)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:secondAnimation];
};

if(![self.selected isEqual: @""]) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:firstAnimation
                     completion:onCompletion];

}
else {
    onCompletion(YES);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)slideAnimation
{
[self.buttonInfoFrame setAlpha:1.0];
[self.buttonSetCourse setAlpha:1.0];
[self.buttonSetCourse setEnabled:YES];

if(![self.selected isEqual: @""])
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.buttonInfoFrame.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 1050;
        frame.origin.y = 150;

        CGRect frame2 = self.buttonSetCourse.frame;
        frame2.origin.x = 1050;
        frame2.origin.y = 526;

        self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;
        self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            CGRect frame = self.buttonInfoFrame.frame;
            frame.origin.x = 757;
            frame.origin.y = 150;

            CGRect frame2 = self.buttonSetCourse.frame;
            frame2.origin.x = 747;
            frame2.origin.y = 526;

            self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;
            self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;
        }];
    }];
}
else
{
    CGRect frame = self.buttonInfoFrame.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 757;
    frame.origin.y = 150;

    CGRect frame2 = self.buttonSetCourse.frame;
    frame2.origin.x = 747;
    frame2.origin.y = 526;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    self.buttonInfoFrame.frame = frame;
    self.buttonSetCourse.frame = frame2;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}
```

Comment: Please also check my answer. It shows how to remove duplicate code.